# Macro to make enums debugger-aware?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, cdb

I am using Qt Creator 4.7.0 with Qt 5.9.2 LTS.
Is there an easy way to make the debugger (*GDB* or *CDB*) aware of your own `enum` types without having to create a custom debugging helper (eg with a macro like maybe `Q_MAKE_DEBUGGING_AWARE`?

So far only "Value of type *xyz*" is displayed for those custom enum values.

Comment: It seems it's an issue inside QtCreator. It worked fine until the update to 4.7.0. I am looking for the solution too.

Answer (score 4):

It worked fine before Qt Creator 4.7.0. I discovered that unchecking **Tools > Options > Debugger > CDB > Use Python dumper** solves this and all my enums are shown correctly in all debugger output windows.